# Upload files individual from multiple file input - by only using one submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

first of all sorry for my bad English. I have hit a point in my project that i can't finde a solution on, so I will ask for help.

---

#### First let me explain a little about what the project is:

The system is a big upload system for a customer. each file there are selected need a Title.

[image]

As you can see I have many "Chose File" that because there need to be a *max* number of files pr categories *(this can be change invidually)* and the Title *(the box beside the orange upload)* are Required if you have chose a file.

#### My problem:

Click upload on each category are ignoring so wanna make *one* button to push there activate the upload for all those files. that easy enough, but here it's come: at the Host this system run on the max "upload size" is 90MB so when I have multiple files at the same time, its hit really quick the max.

#### This is how the HTML looks:

```
<form method='POST' accept-charset='UTF-8' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
    <div class="inputs">
        <label for="uMP1">Vælg Fil</label>
        <input type="text" name='titles[]'>
        <!-- Thumbnail -->
        <div class="thumbnail" id="MP1"></div>
        <!-- File -->
        <input id="uMP1" name='files[]' type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <label for="uMP2">Vælg Fil</label>
        <input type="text" name='titles[]'>
        <!-- Thumbnail -->
        <div class="thumbnail" id="MP2"></div>
        <!-- File -->
        <input id="uMP2" name='files[]' type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <label for="uMP3">Vælg Fil</label>
        <input type="text" name='titles[]'>
        <!-- Thumbnail -->
        <div class="thumbnail" id="MP3"></div>
        <!-- File -->
        <input id="uMP3" name='files[]' type="file">
   </div>
   <input type="Submit" name='Upload' value="Upload">
</form>
```

Is there any there can help me make this script or know a plugin there can do this?

> **PS:** Do not have access to the php.ini

Comment: Hope I have explain it good enough

Comment: You need to add one more bold section: "What I have already tried:"

Comment: @mkaatman Okay wait a second

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have tried to it in PHP only but that not work, and im new to jQuery so I really don't know anything about how to make a function like that

Answer (score 0):

Premise that I have never used PHP, but ASPNET Core 2.1
I also had a similar problem and the solution is to give different names for each input file.
For example:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <label for="uMP1">Vælg Fil</label>
    <input type="text" name='titles[]'>
    <!-- Thumbnail -->
    <div class="thumbnail" id="MP1"></div>
    <!-- File -->
    <input id="uMP1" name='files1' type="file">
</div>
<div class="inputs">
    <label for="uMP2">Vælg Fil</label>
    <input type="text" name='titles[]'>
    <!-- Thumbnail -->
    <div class="thumbnail" id="MP2"></div>
    <!-- File -->
    <input id="uMP2" name='files2' type="file">
</div>
```